# jQuery DataTable with SQLSRV and JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  Is this not the right format for performing an ajax call and returning JSON?

I am trying to return JSON to populate a DataTable.  I have done something very similar to this before, but I am unable to make it work this time.

Here is the script ("api/exceptions_all.php") where I am using SQLSRV to return the JSON:

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database.php");

   $select = "SELECT
               ''
               ,[FOR_PARTNER] 
               ,[FOR_NAME]
               ,[SHP_PARTNER]
               ,[SHP_NAME]
               ,[MODDATE]
               ,[MODUSER]
               ,[ID]
             FROM [main].[dbo].[for_exceptions]";

 $query = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $select) or die(sqlsrv_errors());
 $out = array();

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
 {
   $out[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode( $out );
 sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);

 ?>
```

Now here is my javascript file ("exceptions.js") where I am trying to retrieve the JSON and print it in the datatable:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "type": 'POST',
     "ajax": 'api/exceptions_all.php',
     "data": data,
     "dataType": 'json',
     "bDestroy": true
   });
 });
```

I keep getting an error stating "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" referring to "data": data above.

In my HTML file, I have the table where the DataTable should be populated:

```
 <table id="example1">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Edit</th>
     <th>FF Partner Code</th>
     <th>FF Name</th>
     <th>SHP Partner Code</th>
     <th>SHP Name</th>  
     <th>Modified Date</th>
     <th>Modified User</th>
     <th>ID</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 // datatable should be here
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing you are missing to declare the $out[] array out of while loop ;

```
     <?php
     include("../include/database.php");

     $select = "SELECT
           ''
           ,[FOR_PARTNER] 
           ,[FOR_NAME]
           ,[SHP_PARTNER]
           ,[SHP_NAME]
           ,[MODDATE]
           ,[MODUSER]
           ,[ID]
         FROM [main].[dbo].[for_exceptions]";

     $query = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $select) or die(sqlsrv_errors());

     $out=array();**// add this line** 
     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
     {
     $out[] = $row;
     }
     echo json_encode( $out );
     sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);

   ?>
```

Comment: Sorry - I did indeed have the line you referred to.  I just edited my question.  Still having the same problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the DataTables plugin for jQuery...

Something like this maybe...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
     "ajax": 'api/exceptions_all.php'
   });
});
```

This is directly from the Docs...